# How to force creating a conformal mesh interface between zones in Fluent?

Tags: cfd, porous-medium, fluent

I am trying to perform simple 2D CFD analysis on Fluent having 3 adjacent zones(inlet, porous and outlet).
[image: Zones figure]

The problem I have is whenever I select non-equilibrium thermal model in porous zone in *Cell Zone Conditions* (as follows)
[image]

I get the following error:

> A duplicate of this zone cannot be generated automatically, as it
> contains a non-conformal mesh interface.
>
> You must manually make a copy
> the porous fluid zone and define it as a solid zone before you enable
> the non-equilibrium thermal model.

AFAIK, a non-conformal mesh interface is an interface which does not have equal number of nodes on both sides, but it seems to me (visually) that I have an equal number of nodes on both sides (between zones):

[image]

So how can I make sure that I have conformal mesh interface between the fluid zones and the porous zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue addressed in Fluent user guide:

> Parts are groups or collections of bodies. Parts can include multiple
> bodies and are then referred to as multibody parts. ***If your
> geometry contains multiple parts then each part will be meshed with
> separate meshes with no connection between them, even if they
> apparently share faces.***
>
> You can convert a geometry which has multiple parts into one with a
> single part by using the Form New Part functionality in the ANSYS
> DesignModeler application. Simply select all of the bodies and then
> select Tools > Form New Part. If you have an external geometry file
> that has multiple parts that you wish to mesh with one mesh, then you
> will have to import it into the DesignModeler application first and
> perform this operation, rather than importing it directly into the
> ANSYS Meshing application.

From DesignModeler:

[image]

The whole geometry is now a one part (still with separate zones) with a conformal interface between the zones.